# how to plot the monthly average temperature over the entire length of the data set

Tags: r

I am a beginner of R.
The question is that you have this data set ready plot the monthly average temperature over the entire length of the data set. That is, on the x-axis plot the months (numbered 1, 2, 3…. 12, 13, 14,…), while on the y-axis plot the monthly averages.

I already have the data set like this 
[image]

my attempt is

```
plot(Temp$month,Temp$averagetemp)
```

the result is [image]

I wonder how to change the code.

Comment: you need to create a date:`plot(as.Date(paste0(Temp$year, '-', Temp$month, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), Temp$averagetemp)`

Comment: See also `zoo::as.yearmon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new variable that counts by months:

```
Temp$month_addative <- Temp$month + (Temp$year-min(Temp$year))*12
plot(Temp$month_additive,Temp$averagetemp)
```

Assuming 2003 is your lowest year, this will add 12 for every year past 2003 to the month number, creating a cumulative count of months.

Comment: My pleasure :) You should use the check mark to mark the question as answered if you consider your problem solved